# Finding the maximum subsequence of a sequence of integers

Tags: c++, c++11

So my task says *"Create a function that receives vector and enum type variable that can only have values Increment or Decrement, and according to those two, find the maximum subsequence of a sequence of integers that are powers of two, which are stored in the vector, and return them in form of `deque of vectors`"*.
So basically what I need to do is find the maximum increment/decrement subsequence of numbers, which also happen to be powers of two, and store every subsequence in seperate vector, and return the result as a deque of vectors.

I've done the `IsItPower` function using `Bitwise AND`, and also `FindSequence` function. But I'm having issues pushing vectors into deque. `push_back` function implementation is obviously wrong, but I've put it there just to describe what I actually want to do. Here's the function:

**NOTE**: I haven't dealt with the decrement part of function, that's not the point, just imagine it having to return increment subsequences.

**QUESTION**: How do I push elements to vectors, then push those very vectors to deques later on, after the below described condition returns false?

```
typedef std::deque<int> Dec;
typedef std::vector<int> Vec;
typedef std::deque<std::vector<int>> DecVec;
enum Direction
{
    Increment,
    Decrement
};
DecVec FindSequence(Vec v, Direction var)
{
    DecVec dv;
    Vec v1;
    int counter(0);
    for (int i(0); i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (IsItPower(v.at(i)) == true && (i == 0 && v.at(i + 1) > v.at(i) || i == v.size() - 1 && v.at(i) > v.at(i - 1) || v.at(i) > v.at(i - 1)))
        {
            v1.push_back(v.at(i));
        }
        else if (!(IsItPower(v.at(i)) == true && (i == 0 && v.at(i + 1) > v.at(i) || i == v.size() - 1 && v.at(i) > v.at(i - 1) || v.at(i) > v.at(i - 1))))
        {
            dv.at(counter).push_back(v1);
            brojac++;
        }
    }
    return dv;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your specific question? You have described your confusing "task" in detail, but your question on stackoverflow.com fails to actually state a specific programming question. "How do I do this", or "Why doesn't this work", or "I'm having issues", without even explaining exacly how it "does not work", or what the specific issues are, is not a specific question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Question updated, I hope it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: Well, the answer to both of your question is the same: use `push_back()`. That's how you push element into either a vector or a deque. That's it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So I can push a vector into deque using `push_back` ?

Comment: If it's a deque of vectors, sure. If it's a deque of all elements in a vector, iterate over each element in the vector, and push it back into the deque individually.

Comment: Questions should contain a [MCVE].  And don't start sentences with "So". I get all triggered.

Comment: @JiveDadson It has all the above, it's just the task that's a bit confusing. And I'm not a native English speaker, didn't know such phrases could upset someone at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dv.at(counter).push_back(v1);` you try to push a `vector<int>` `v1` into another `vector<int>` `dv[0]`. If you want to push `v1` to the back of `dv`, just write

```
dv.push_back(v1);
```

And then you probably want to clear `v1`, otherwise it will keep growing.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. I'd also like to ask another question that's related. The way my function is made, it pushes the same vector in the deque, over and over again if the first condition is false. That's okay when I actually need it to send that vector (when it finds one subsequence it needs to send it do deque, and continue searching for others, and so on), but when there's no subsequence it just needs to keep on moving until it finds another one. How do I make that happen?